# load and display content progressively

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, dotnetnuke

Good day to everyone..

I've developed a dotnetnuke module, in which I potentially dislpay a quite large amount of data, and the page takes quite a long time to be loaded into the browser.
At the moment, during page_load I simply get my data from DB and use it as datasource to populate a datagrid.

What I want to do is to load and display the page content progressively, in order to quickly display the page to the user and then populate the datagrid a piece at a time, enhancing the user experience. I'm trying to implement AJAX functionality to achieve this, but I'm having hard times figuring out how.

I started giving a look this morning, and by now I'm able to do some basic ajax implamentation in dotnentnuke, but I'm having difficulties finding tutorials obout similar implementation, or to figure it out by myself.

If It is possible to achieve this without altering the current structure, fetching data progressively and appending rows to the DataGrid, it will be ok, but if it will result in poor performance, I prefer to change everything and do it in another way.

Also, I thought AJAX would be the best option, but I can evaluate the possibility to implement different solutions if the application will benefit from it.

Thank you in advance,

Alberto

[EDIT]

I have partially solved my problem:

I altered the SQL Stored Procedure so to retrieve "n" rows starting from a specific index "x".

At each cycle of an asp:timer, I fetch a group of "n" rows, and save into the viewstate the next starting index "x", in order to be ready for fetching the next group of rows.

At ths point, at each cycle I have a piece of my entire list, and I'm ready to display it to the user.

Here lies the last problem: Is it possible to APPEND the new rows to the already DataBound items??

As mentioned in the original post, at the moment I'm using an asp:datagrid. There's no problem in changing the control to display data, but I'm not able to find reference to any control that has a "partial databinding" functionality.

The only obvious solution for now is that of adding directly each control to my page, but to me it seems everything but an "elegant" one; In addition, each row contains 13 controls placed inside a quite complex TemplateColumn in my datagrid..

Anyone has a better idea?

Thank you in advance

[EDIT 2]

I'm getting closer to a solution (actually two possible solutions)

- SOLUTION A
  By getting more familiar with ajax and dynamic added control, I'm techincally able to "fake" the data display of the datagrid by dynamically adding the controls.
- SOLUTION B
  The solution that I'm testing now is that

Step 1 - databind all the rows to the datagrid with only a very little part of the data, in order to have all the rows but drastically reducing loading time.

Step 2 - during asyncpostbacks, I fetch groups of rows and fill in the rest of the data.

I'll update again when I have some good result.

In the meantime, I'm still accepting suggestions and/or alternative solutions

Godd day!

Comment: Note: The datagrid disaplys is list with basic information about the content; when I click a button in a specific row, the module does a postBack, hides the datagrid and displays another section of the page with additional data, and where I can edit the content. When saving, closing or deleting the selected item, another postBack happens, returning to the datagrid and reloading data in order to eventualy remove or change the modified item. This functionality must remain in the final product.
Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Because "This functionality must remain in the final product" as you commented i suggest two solutions for you :

First is to implementing AJAX "Please tell us where your problem is exactly"

Second solution is like a trick "i did it before"

you don't have to bind all data every time, you can modify your SQL procedure by adding a new column for rows ranks or rows numbers you might use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to do that.
Now lets go back to the grid in your module, lets say your grid page size is 10 rows,
at page_load event in not page.postback you bind the result for the following SQL Command 
"Select -Columns- from Your_StoredProcedure_Or_View where RowNumber between 1 and 10"

If page.postback in page_load event you bind the result for the following SQL Command

"Select -Columns- from Your_StoredProcedure_Or_View where RowNumber between 20 and 30"

--if page(3) for example --

and you have to store the current page in a variable or in query string maybe.
It's just works,

Comment: Hi Alaaeddin, thank you for answering. The "functionality that must remain in the final product", is the capability of doing full postbacks to load the details of the selecte row (no more a problem)  As I said in the [EDIT], I already modified the stored procedure to fetch rows by groups (for example 10 rows each time). Unfortunatley, in my case paging is not an option, because I need ALL the rows to be displayed togheter. In fact, my question was about "appending" now rows at the previously databound items in a datagrid. Thank you again!